# Continuous monitoring of AWS resource presence

Tags: amazon-web-services, monitoring

I have a bunch of AWS resources, e.g. EC2, ECS, API Gateway, Lambda, etc.

The problem is that I'm not only admin on AWS and other administrators could delete some resources by reason like wrong tagging or by human mistake.

Unfortunately IAM and /or monitoring solutions (zabbix, nagios, etc.) are not a solution in this particular situation.

So the question is how can I monitor AWS resource presence continuously by calling AWS API and checking response?

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Server Fault](http://serverfault.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With CloudTrail, you can log, continuously monitor, and retain account activity related to actions across your AWS infrastructure. CloudTrail provides event history of your AWS account activity, including actions taken through the AWS Management Console, AWS SDKs, command line tools, and other AWS services. This event history simplifies security analysis, resource change tracking, and troubleshooting. https://aws.amazon.com/cloudtrail/?nc1=h_ls

Answer (score 1):

It is possible to create Cloudwatch alarms that will treat missing datapoints as breaching the threshold.

If you can find a metric for all of your resources that should be constantly outputting data when the resource is in a healthy state (e.g. CPU utilization on an ec2 instance), then by treating missing data as breaching, these alarms should fire if the resource is deleted (potentially after some time, depending on the threshold)